# Yii How to render Page NAME instead, ID in URL

Tags: yii, actionview, yii-url-manager

I want to render page name through URL request parameter.

like -

```
r=page/view&name=page_name
```

instead of id - `r=page/view&id=1`

please i need to know what i can do in 
**actionview()**, **viewfile** and **urlmanager** (code generated by gii)

Help to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this -

your request url - `r=page/view&name=page`

In your action controller -

```
public function actionView(){

   if(isset($_REQUEST['name']) && !empty($_REQUEST['name'])){

    $page_name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $this->render($page_name);
   }
}
```

Comment: Rohit Suthar Thanks very much u saved me 
ok another question plz what if i want that URL
r=page/view&name=pagename TO  sitname/page/pagename
Thanks again man

Comment: @OsamaDiab if your url like this - `sitname/page/pagename` then first you need to configure in your **urlManager**